# Why error ''self' used before self.init call' when using DispatchQueue in init?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I'm getting those errors in the code below `(Xcode 9)`:

```
convenience init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject], context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Photo", in: context) else {
        fatalError("No Entity name Found")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        self.title = dictionary[FlickrClient.JSONResponseKeys.title] as? String
        self.path = dictionary[FlickrClient.JSONResponseKeys.mediumURL] as? String
    }
}
```

it works fine without the `DispatchQueue`.main.async, but I need to the implement it because the app is not threaded safe. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don’t post pictures of code or errors, paste the text into your post.

Comment: I did, errors shown on image are in the title

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using `self` inside the closure that you pass to `DispatchQueue.main.async`. When you use `self` inside a closure, it is captured by the closure, which counts as passing `self` to something. You can't do that before you've finished initializing `self`.

Plus, think about it. If that were allowed, the initializer would complete before the initialization had actually finished, since the main thread still has work to do and the initializer is pretty much done as soon as it does the handoff.

If you need to initialize something asynchronously, use the factory pattern instead:

```
static func make(foo: Foo, bar: Bar, baz: Whatever, handler: (Widget) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let thingy = Thingy(xyzzy: plugh) else { fatalError("I DON'T LIKE SPAM") }

        handler(Widget(thingy: thingy))
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed the factory pattern, still same issue. I get, however, how using self inside the closure is causing this problem. I will review and edit the code. Thank you